# How to auto select a item from dropdownlist when page is loaded

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I need to auto select an item from dropdownlist when page is loaded.
.aspx code:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="True" AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="fullname" DataValueField="fullname">
  <asp:ListItem>Any</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:PHSNew %>" SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT [fullname] FROM [web_Users] WHERE ([role] = @role) ORDER BY [fullname]">
  <SelectParameters>
     <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="md" Name="role" Type="String" />
  </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Now for example if dropdownlist has 4 items (John, Albert, Epstien and Any).
in .cs file I run sql query to get a string name, from database which should be selected in this dropdown.

I just used `DropDownList1.selectedValue= name`. It worked 
But now the problem is the data in database keeps on changing. I may get string name = "Renzo". Renzo WAS part of the database but now it's removed. In that case I have to select "Any".
I tried executing this code:

```
string s = "Albert";
ListItemCollection li = DropDownList1.Items;

foreach (ListItem l in li)
{
    string s1 = l.ToString();
    if (l.ToString() == s)
    {
        DropDownList1.SelectedValue = s;
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        DropDownList1.SelectedValue = "Any";
    }
}
```

**And I am calling this code in Page_Load**.

But I am able to get only one item from DropDownlist1 and that is "Any".
How can I get all items and auto select a particular item from dropdownlist?

Comment: try ` if (l.ToString().ToLower() == s.ToLower())`

Comment: i don't get what you need to do exactly, please explain more

Comment: yeah i guess u r correct but
initially, i am getting only one item in ListItemCollections.
and its value is "Any"
How can i get all items (John, Albert, Epstien and Any).

Comment: yeah sure......
in my database i have a table wch has list of names like(John, Albert, Epstien) and through sqldatasource i get these items into dropdownlist.

Now when you choose one row from a table, i run a sql query wch gives me many attributes and "name" is one among them.
Whatever i get in "name" should be auto selected in dropdownlist. 
You may get "name" as John, Albert, Epstien or any other since database keeps on changing. So if "name" is apart from John, Albert, Epstien then i have to choose "Any". 
i used above code to execute but not able to do it.

Comment: and item in dropdownlist should be auto selected as soon as page is loaded (after selecting row from table).

Comment: How are you adding the "Any" option to the dropdown?  Can you post more of your `Page_Load` method?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue with your code is that you are using `l.ToString()`.  You would want to use `l.Value` instead in your comparison.

Another way of doing this you can use the find methods of the item collection.

```
string s = "Albert";

ListItem li = DropDownList1.Items.FindByValue(s);
if (li != null)
{
    li.Selected = true;
}
else
{
    DropDownList1.SelectedValue = "Any";
}
```

Comment: true...
but
            ListItemCollection li = DropDownList1.Items;
            int size = li.Count; here i am getting the size is equal to one .  That means there is only one item in dropdownlist but ideally i should get 4.
I am calling the code in Page_load. is this the reason i am getting only one item in Dropdownlist.items ??
if i get all items then i can compare and autoselect.